# big query materialized view; create a materialized view using an (inner) join

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

Hopefully someone can help me move forward cause it seems I'm stuck.

I've read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create) carefully on how to create a materialized view, however I'm getting this unclear error;

`Materialized view query contains unsupported feature.`

I know the error is in the join, if I remove it, the error disappears as well, however inner joins should be supported when looking at the documentation, so I'm a little bit lost right now.

**Background**: we use firestore and its BigQuery Extension to get our collection into bigQuery. for performance reasons I'm looking into the materialized view option.

**Question**: Basically what I want is to get the latest document from the (Firestore Bigquery Extension) changelog table.
I first gather the latest timestamp per document_id, I then want to retrieve the actual document (the `data` column) from the data table.

**More specifically**; can someone help to;

1. A; figure out what I'm doing wrong
2. B; or tell me how I create a materialized view where I;

   - always have access to the latest document version
   - exclude deleted documents (`operation` = 'DELETE`) from the result set

All help is very much appreciated!

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW `XXX.XXX.view_name` AS
  WITH `ids` AS (
    SELECT
      `document_name`,
      MAX(`timestamp`) AS `timestamp`,
    FROM `XXX.XXX.id_table`
    GROUP BY `document_name`
  )

  SELECT
    `d`.`data`
  FROM `XXX.XXX.data_table` AS `d`
  INNER JOIN `ids` AS `i` ON (
    `i`.`timestamp` = `d`.`timestamp`
    `i`.`document_name` = `d`.`document_name`
  )
  WHERE `operation` != 'DELETE'
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my guess based the current documentation:
[Document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#query_limitations) says:
"Aggregates in the materialized view query must be outputs. Computing or filtering based on an aggregated value is not supported."

In your "WITH" clause you have used MAX(timestamp) aggregate function and that column you are using it in join's ON computation. And probably thats why it not supported.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I think you're right. a colleague reached the same conclusion. do you perhaps have any idea/suggestion on how I should go about this?

Comment: 1] If you make first table (with: with clause) into a native table, it will work. Thats the straight forward solution (but your business logic may or may not allow it)
OR 
2] Have one more column in `XXX.XXX.id_table` table for max_timestamp that way you do not need to  create first WITH clause and use the native table with new max_timestamp column as is. that way no computational column rule will hinder it.